# =importhtml Google Sheets Multiple Error Messages

Tags: html, excel, google-sheets

Trying to scrape data from two pages of the same website to research secondary gift card market.

NOTE: Had to change the syntax because my rep is too low to post multiple links. There is a key at the bottom of the post.

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/sell-a-gift-card-old/","table", 1)
&
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/sell-a-gift-card-old/","table", 2)
```

Both of those are working, but when I try:

```
=importhtml("http://www.giftcardgranny.com/top-deals/","table",1)
```

I am getting different error messages from `Imported content is empty` to `Could not fetch URL`, seemingly random as to which one comes up.

I have researched a good amount and I know since an update was made in early/mid 2015 this formula has been buggy, but I am thinking for me it may not be working because of the pagination on the second URL vs no pagination on the first URL?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. What, in particular, do you need help with?

Comment: I am trying to get the table in =importhtml("*giftcardgranny(dotcom)/top-deals/","table",1), including the data through all of the pagination, to load into a google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for both pages, the `sell-a-gift-card-old` page is built as a table in HTML, which is why it works. The `top-deals` page data is held in JavaScript arrays, so you'll need to use a different method to get the information. It returns empty because there *is* no table to return.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions?

Comment: @thailer35 Other than copying and pasting the object into your code every few days, no. There is no API available for automatic data collection and processing.